# Retrieving a row from the GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm would like to retrieve a cell from a selected row in GridView. Please tell me how I might accomplish this.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow
Dim cell2 as string = row.cells(1).text
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#,

```
GridViewRow GVR = gridview.SelectedRow;
string dd = GVR.Cells[1].Text;
```